# Technical reason we cannot iterate with forEach() over Map.prototype.keys()

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

If I create a Map instance like so:

```
let m = new Map()
```

I cannot iterative over it's keys like so:

```
m.keys().forEach()
```

why is that?

I can iterative over it's key-value pairs like so:

```
m.forEach((v,k) => {})
```

what is the reason for this?

Comment: [MDN Map keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) *"The keys() method returns a **new Iterator object** that contains the keys for each element in the Map object in insertion order."*

Comment: You should be able to do `m.keys().each(function(key) {})`

Comment: for(key of m.keys()) ...

Comment: Ok so it's the simple difference between an Iterator vs. an Array

Comment: I feel like this is a reasonable question, and doesn't deserve any downvotes. The accepted answer got 5 upvotes in less than 2 hours, so I feel like this helps people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map.prototype.keys()` returns an `Iterator` object, not an `Array`, which has no `.forEach()` function in it's prototype.

What you can do, however, is the following:

```
let map = new Map();
Array.from(map.keys()).forEach(callback);
```

That will convert the `Iterator` object into an `Array`, and you can use the `.forEach()` method freely. Alternatively, you can use the spread syntax to accomplish the same goal:

```
let map = new Map();
let keys = [ ...myMap.keys() ].forEach(callback);
```

Comment: Makes me wonder if you can just do  `(...myMap.keys()).forEach()` :)